# Execute gnome-terminal from remote server

Tags: php, centos, gnome-terminal

Alright, so I have a VPS running with gnome-terminal, and I'm using the following php script execute commands on the remote server.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('IP address');
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'rthtrhtrhrthrthrth')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('gnome-terminal -e java -jar run.jar --window-with-profile=b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9');
?>
```

Which when I run the script I get the following error

> ** (gnome-terminal:1952): WARNING **: Could not open X display Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:

I'm trying to get it to run a command from a remote server which will execute in gnome-terminal and open the jar file. Pretty much when the shell command is executed on my remote server, connects to ssh and runs the gnome-terminal command to open up a desktop application on that VPS.

Is this possible or am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE

In Putty I've gotten it to work by issueing the following commands

```
export DISPLAY=:1
gnome-terminal -e "java -jar file.jar"
```

But still trying to execute it with my web server using

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('IP address');
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'rthtrhtrhrthrthrth')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('export DISPLAY=:1');
echo $ssh->exec('gnome-terminal -e "java -jar run.jar"');
?>
```

I'm still getting the error where it cannot open X display. I'm only trying to pass this to the VPS, not display anything on the web server

Comment: try a manual ssh connection to that server and run your code, if it not fails try to use escapeshellarg() to your shell arguments.

Comment: It will do the same thing.@NicolòCozzani

Comment: What I'm trying to do is open an application through SSH and have it forwarded to gnome-desktop on the VPS

Answer (score 0):

Does the VPS have an X running ?
I would suggest a slightly different approach:
Rather than running gnome-terminal, you might as well execute stuff directly using ssh. 
Bare in mind that your php will hang until java is finised. Add a "&" at the end of your command if you want it detached from ssh.

Comment: Yes it has it running, as I stated I can get it to work and open the application in the desktop environment on the VPS, but trying to execute it on the web server I can't get it to work with export display=:1 in my php script though

Comment: I'm able to remotely do it through SSH and it opens the application on the server, just can't get it to work with my php script.

Comment: Can it be a permission thing pertaining to X. In the olden days I was stuck doing "xhost+" all over the place.

Comment: I don't think so since I can execute it in putty outside of X